# PCs on LAN randomly are unable to login to the domain server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I have ~100 PCs connected to a Microsoft domain server on a LAN (Ethernet). When I do a wake on LAN, one or more PCs at random give the error message "Domain Server unavailable to process login request".

Restarting the affected PCs or logging in manually will work, but I am not sure what the root cause of the issue is

PCs are running windows 7, and the server is windows server 2008

Comment: When you get that message, can you ping the domain controller?  What DNS servers does the computer try to connect to at that time?

Comment: It's a single domain server on the same LAN. Yes, I can ping the server after logging in. The computers are setup to login automatically, and when one computer fails to login automatically, I get that message. This happens sporadically and it seems random as to which computers fail to login. Usually it's just one or two machines.

Comment: You still didn't answer about the DNS server when the problem is happining.  Also, what DHCP server is shown when you use IPConfig/ALL when the problem is happining.

Comment: The DNS server is pointing to the IPv4 address of he windows 2008 server.

Comment: DHCP is not enabled (DHCP enabled = No)

Comment: If your server's name is dc.example.com, what happens if you ping dc?  What happens if you ping example.com?   (Right, the name of the domain, without a computer name)  How about "nltest /DCLIST:example.com"?  (Try all these on a machine that isn't working.)  Note that [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) is probably the better site for this situation.